# Poster pillar using Meteor Slides?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, meteor-slides

I'm a bit experimenting with some idea and I'm wondering if I can achieve my vision using Meteor Slides. Let me explain the basic idea first:

I want to have some sort of poster pillar, where the current slide would be the poster or some promotion - of course, rather big but that's not a problem. I would also like to achieve the effect of the other posters being "on the edge" of that pillar, but I have no idea how to do that.

So far I figured out that a good idea would be to create a transparent .png file that will serve as the pillar overlay and then every slide will just fit inside that pillar. Sounds right I guess, but I can't get this right no matter what: I tried using z-index to get the .png on top of the slide image but it just doesn't work. Any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meteor-slides/

Comment: Can you show examples of what you tried and what did not work?

Comment: @jedrus07 I've created a .png image of the pillar, where the "inside" is transparent, so the slides will be visible through it. I found a div with class of .meteor-slides .meteor-clip and added to its CSS a background of said .png file. Works. Then I added few posters and tried apllying z-index lower than the div with the .png background, but it doesn't work. Not sure why, tried applying position: absolute but to no avail. Adding two screenshots that may explain it in better way: http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9638/screen1jx.jpg and http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/3608/screen2cy.jpg

Comment: Any ideas? I'm constantly hitting the wall here~~

Comment: I think we really need to see a code with clear explanation of what it was supposed to do and what does not work. Otherwise the question is too open ended and it keep people from answering it. It may be possible that you are facing a few different problems and number of questions will have to be opened. I recommend checking our faq- http://stackoverflow.com/faq